# how to merge 4 graphs which has different x-axis and y-axis intervals into one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 graphs, two of them are shown below with the data frame and resulting graph

Here is my dataframe (`h1`):

```
h2 <- structure(list(Tool.Module = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", "M_AUB01", 
"M_ETR01", "M_FRA01", "M_FRA01_01", "M_FRA01_02", "M_FRA01_03", 
"M_FRA01_04", "M_KPR01_00", "M_KPR02_00", "M_LAM01", "M_LAM01_01", 
"M_LAM02", "M_LAM02_01", "M_LAY01", "M_LOT01_01", "M_LOT01_02_1", 
"M_LOT01_02_2", "M_LOT01_03_1", "M_LOT01_03_2", "M_LOT01_04", 
"M_TAB01_1", "M_TAB01_2"), class = "factor"), end1 = structure(c(1428984210, 
1428984310, 1428985632, 1428985772, 1428985881, 1428985990, 1428986230, 
1428986332, 1428986460, 1428986580, 1428986700, 1428986780, 1428986923, 
1428987020, 1428988400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("Tool.Module", 
"end1"), row.names = c(7L, 37L, 102L, 111L, 118L, 123L, 140L, 
147L, 156L, 167L, 174L, 180L, 188L, 191L, 280L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
> h1
    Tool.Module                end1
7       M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:03:30
37      M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:05:10
102     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:27:12
111     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:29:32
118     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:31:21
123     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:33:10
140     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:37:10
147     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:38:52
156     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:41:00
167     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:43:00
174     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:45:00
180     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:46:20
188     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:48:43
191     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 06:50:20
280     M_FRA01 2015-04-14 07:13:20
```

Here is the command for the plot:

```
   plot(h1$end1, seq_along(h1$end1), type = "b")
```

[image]

My second dataframe (`h2`):

```
h2 <- structure(list(Tool.Module = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("M_AUB02", 
    "M_ETR02", "M_FRA02", "M_FRA02_01", "M_FRA02_02", "M_FRA02_03", 
    "M_FRA02_04", "M_KPR03_00", "M_KPR04_00", "M_LAM03", "M_LAM03_01", 
    "M_LAM04", "M_LAM04_01", "M_LAY02", "M_LOT02_01", "M_LOT02_02_1", 
    "M_LOT02_02_2", "M_LOT02_03_1", "M_LOT02_03_2", "M_LOT02_04", 
    "M_TAB02_1", "M_TAB02_2"), class = "factor"), end2 = structure(c(1428984300, 
    1428984380, 1428984480, 1428984570, 1428984660, 1428984740, 1428984830, 
    1428984920, 1428985020, 1428985120, 1428985183, 1428985270, 1428985360, 
    1428985450, 1428985540), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("Tool.Module", 
    "end2"), row.names = c(17L, 24L, 34L, 44L, 52L, 60L, 69L, 79L, 
    89L, 99L, 107L, 114L, 124L, 132L, 140L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the command for the plot:

```
plot(h2$end2, seq_along(h2$end2), type = "b")
```

[image]

I would like to show the above both graphs in one box, and i tried the lines concept. Here is the command for the plot:

```
plot(h2$end2, seq_along(h2$end2), type = "b")
    lines(h1$end1,seq_along(h1$end1), type = "b", col = "red")
```

[image: graph using lines concept]

but these is not the way, actual graph which i want look like. Actually i want to show 4 graphs(same like above two) in one box.

Comment: use the multiplot function: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Without any data to reproduce your plot, it's difficult to test, but you could either try `coord_cartesian` or set scale-limits via `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(...))`?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: I saw the link. that is not what i want. i want to show all 3 graphs in one plot(#one graph)

Answer (score 1):

Your  X axis looks the same to me. Since I do not have your data, I am giving here an example

```
library(wikipediatrend)

views1 <-wp_trend(page = "European debt crisis",from = "2010-01-01",to = "2014-12-31",lang = "en",friendly = TRUE,requestFrom = "wp.trend.tester at wptt.wptt",userAgent = TRUE)



views2 <-wp_trend(page = "National debt of the United States",from = "2010-01-01",to = "2014-12-31",lang = "en",friendly = TRUE,requestFrom = "wp.trend.tester at wptt.wptt",userAgent = TRUE)


views3 <-wp_trend(page = "Arab Spring",from = "2010-01-01",to = "2014-12-31",lang = "en",friendly = TRUE,requestFrom = "wp.trend.tester at wptt.wptt",userAgent = TRUE)


views4 <-wp_trend(page = "Greek government-debt crisis",from = "2010-01-01",to = "2014-12-31",lang = "en",friendly = TRUE,requestFrom = "wp.trend.tester at wptt.wptt",userAgent = TRUE)

combview1<-cbind(views1,views2[,2],views3[,2],views4[,2])

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

meltdf1 <- melt(combview1,id="Time")

ggplot(meltdf1,aes(x=Time,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]